# Slack app slower after porting from webhooks to API method

Tags: slack, slack-api

We have a custom slack integration that has been used for a while.
After announce that custom integrations will be deprecated we switched to new app method for our bot.

An issue that we face now, after a switch, is that bot response is much slower, our old integration took ~1s for response and with app method (running same code) it takes ~5s.

Could this be that slack is prioritizing integrations that have greater uptime on the platform?

Comment: What do you mean by "new app method"?? Are you now using the incoming webhook of a Slack app or are you using the API method chat.postMessage?

Comment: we are using API method chat.postMessage

Comment: ok. well, there can be many different causes to this problem. In my opinion it has most likely to do with your code. Please add the relevant part of your code that was ported, e.g. includes the actually sending of the message. And the language / libraries you are using. Ty